# How do I use the width tool and brushes in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs5, tools, brush

I am following this tutorial on [Custom Lettering](http://www.graphicmonkee.com/create-an-easy-hand-lettering-effect-in-illustrator)

In one of the steps, it says " Using the Brush Tool (<kbd>B</kbd>), with the “Basic” brush; use the Width Tool (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>) to adjust the width of our new path"

I tried doing this in Illustrator CS5 but it seems that the width tool is not able to expand my newly created path.

Based on googling, I found this [site](http://tinytutorials.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/adobe-illustrator-cs5-width-tool-and-brushes/) its say's width tools works only on Art Brush and pattern brushes.

I tried using an Art Brush and Pattern brush and I was able to use the Width Tool on them.

I am just confused, how do I make it work on a brush with a basic settings that is based on the tutorial that I am following.

Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second link is correct. The first link is just a poorly worded or thought out tutorial.

The "Basic" option in the Brush Panel is **not** really a brush at all. In fact, it means...

> Remove brush strokes from selected paths and reduce to a **basic** stroke".

(Horrible naming or at least placement of the "Basic" option by Adobe.)

To use it, you must **first draw the path, and THEN select it, THEN click the "basic" option in the Brush Panel.** (thus removing the default calligraphy brush which will be applied to the path you just drew. Making the path a standard path, and the Width Tool will then work.)

If you just grab the brush tool, click "basic" then draw -- what actually happens is the default calligraphy brush gets applied to the path. Since you are using the Brush Tool, it's assumes you want *some sort* of brush stroke. Again "Basic" is **not** a brush. It is equivalent to the "remove brush stroke" command.

You don't need a brush if you have the **Width Tool**. Just draw a path using the Pen or Pencil tools... then use the Width Tool.

Comment: Thanks Scott!  I was just following the tutorials so as to learn some techniques.  Anyhow, you are right  and learned something new today.  Many thanks from a newbie like me.